# Revert gnome-shell version

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-gnome

I installed [Gnome 40](https://launchpad.net/%7Eshemgp/+archive/ubuntu/gnome-40) as a test version on Ubuntu 21.04, but I would like to revert to gnome-shell 3.38 how might I safely do this?

Comment: consider why you wish to do so. If it is due to a bug, search the bug tracker for existing tasks. If there is none, add a new one; it is better to correct bugs, or at least warn other users of possible issues. Reverting to an earlier version of GNOME may not be the best idea in the long run as it may eventually break your system.

Comment: Well, I just wanted to get back to the stock version of Ubuntu for stability's sake. And 3.38 is what is standard on 21.04.

Comment: The Gnome session of 40.0 is rock solid for me. The Ubuntu session indeed has glitches.

Comment: I was fine on 40.0 but as soon as the PPA bumped me up to 40.1 my whole environment went banana's so decided to just jump back. If I could lock it at 40 that would be nice too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `ppa-purge` utility to revert GNOME Shell version by the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:shemgp/gnome-40
```

and then reboot.